# Проблема при инициализации дескриптора вершинного шейдера

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Я изучаю OpenGL, и нахожусь на этапе изучения шейдеров, но у меня возникла проблема, при инициализации дескриптора для вершинного шейдера следующим синтаксисом:

```c
GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
```

Я получаю ошибку: "Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x7766F949 в LearnOpenGL.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при исполнении по адресу 0x00000000.". Для изучения я использую набор opengl32.lib + glfw3.lib + glew32s.lib + MSVS 2017.

P.S. Немного почитав о причинах ошибки описанной выше, я выяснил что подобное возникает если происходит переполнение переменной, но в моём случае эта версия не состоятельна. А ничего иного мне не удалось найти.

Вот полный код:

```
// GLEW до GLFW
// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char* vertexShaderCode = { "#version 330 core"\
    "layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;"\
    "void main() {"\
    "gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0); }" };

int main(void) {
    int width = 0, height = 0;
    GLuint vbo = 0;
    GLint success = 0;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    GLuint vertexShader;
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    GLfloat vertices[] = { // Вершины треугольника
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    glfwInit(); // Инициализация GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // Задается минимальная требуемая версия OpenGL. (Мажорная) 
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3); // Минорная
    //Установка профайла для которого создается контекст
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE); //Выключение возможности изменения размера окна

    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n%s\n", infoLog);
    }

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    if (window == nullptr) {
        printf("Failed to create GLFW window");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        printf("Failed to initialize GLEW");
        return -1;
    }

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        // some code
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не знаю где вы вычитали про переполнение переменной, но сдесь явно идет разыменование `nullptr`

Comment: Мне кажется что дело не в разыменовании nullptr, а в самой функции, потому что если её вызвать, без присваивания значения переменной, то ошибка всё равно остаётся.

Comment: ну а что по-вашему происходит при вызове функции? Конечно, обращение по указателю (чем и является функция). Посмотри чему равна у вас эта функция - если вылет на ней, то вы увидите там nullptr

Comment: Я не в коем случае не критикую Ваш путь. Лично я изучал шейдеры и графическое программирование на примере webgl, это конечно не совсем то же самое что opengl, однако очень близко. с Webgl быстрее и проще, чем в случае с c++ получить рабочий пример или запустить и начать изучать пример из сети. https://bl.ocks.org/strangerintheq/388b3363cacb07686c1b70669720c1ec

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Я обнаружил что glCreateShader, в моём случае - это макрос, определённый в glew.h. Дайте мне совет, пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: @Centrix Уже написали ниже. Сначала `glflCreateWindow`, потом `glewInit`, и только потом можно использовать opengl.

Comment: Не исправляйте исходный код с ошибками на исправленный, это вводит в заблуждение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дежа вю? `glfwCreateWindow` вызывается до инициализации `glfw`, результаты обоих вызовов, прежде чем идти дальше, не проверяются.

Comment: Спасибо, я исправил код, но делу это ни как не помогло.

Comment: @Centrix Вы по-прежнему вызываете glfwCreateWindow после того, как пытаетесь использовать контекст. Эту функцию необходимо вызывать после `glfwWindowHint`